# Is there anything that I am missing?

Tags: javascript

I created a checkbox and apply these attributes

```
let box = document.createElement('input');
box.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
box.setAttribute("id","box");
box.setAttribute("onclick","checkBox(this)");
```

This is the function

```
function checkBox(para2){
    let condition = box.checked;
    if (condition === true) {
        para2.parentNode.style.opacity = '0.5'
        para2.parentNode.style.textDecoration = "line-through"

    }
    if (condition === false) {
        para2.parentNode.style.opacity = "1";
        para2.parentNode.style.textDecoration = "none";
    }
}
```

When I click on first checkbox, style works. But when I click on other children it doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: style is not working on other childs

Comment: Can you provide the code with the child elements?

Comment: It's my HTML code
    <div id="container">
        <ul id="list">
            
        </ul>
    </div>

Comment: let parent = document.getElementById('list');
    let child = document.createElement('li');
    child.setAttribute("class","text");
    parent.appendChild(child);

    let box = document.createElement('input');

    box.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
    box.setAttribute("id","box");
    box.setAttribute("onclick","checkBox(this)");

    child.appendChild(box);

Comment: Can you please put the code in your question so it is a little more understandable?

Answer (score 0):

In your checkBox function,

```
 let condition = box.checked;
```

This line specifically checks whether the checkbox "box" is checked. Since you are having multiple checkboxes, I believe you may have box2, box3, etc.

As a solution, you can introduce a "name" attribute to your checkboxes and use a query selector to identify which ones are checked.

```
 let condition = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="color"]');
    condition.forEach((cb) => {
        if (cb.checked === true) {
          // your code
        } else {
          // your code
        }
        
    });
```

Note: there might be many other possible ways to do this. This is the one that came to my mind right now